# Where to config BrowserSettings for CefSharp.Winforms

Tags: cefsharp

My wpf application use Cefsharp.Winforms hosted in WindowsFormsHost control, everything works except:
I create a popup with transparent background, but it looks like dark background. Then I found [this](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/2127) issue,

Then I want to config BrowserSettings.BackgroundColor with no luck.
First I referenced [here](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#cefsettings-and-browsersettings):

But it is for wpf example, and when I config like that, an error said: BrowserSettings does not existed in Cefsharp.core.

Then I config either after IsBrowserInitialized, or right below InitializeComponent(), all failed, when I debugged, it said the BrowserSettings null. the code is below:

```
this.browser.BrowserSettings.BackgroundColor = 0x00FFFFFF;
```

How can I set transparent background for browser? thanks very much!

My cefsharp version is: 81.3.100.

==============================================================
not work after switch to wpf version:

```
        <cefwpf:ChromiumWebBrowser x:Name="browser" IsBrowserInitializedChanged="browser_IsBrowserInitializedChanged">
            <cefwpf:ChromiumWebBrowser.BrowserSettings>
                <cefSharpCore:BrowserSettings BackgroundColor="Red"/>
            </cefwpf:ChromiumWebBrowser.BrowserSettings>
        </cefwpf:ChromiumWebBrowser>
```

Comment: The WinForms version does not support transparency.

Comment: Any workaround? Could I switch to wpf version without performance loss?

Comment: After switch wpf version, still not work just like winforms.

Comment: The WPF version supports transparency, there will be performance loss. CefSharp is one of many chromium embedded framework wrappers. There is https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/issues/2315/allow-transparent-browser-for-windowed which was closed as don't fix.

Comment: See http://cefsharp.github.io/api/81.3.x/html/P_CefSharp_BrowserSettings_BackgroundColor.htm you need to specify the value as a uint. You'll need to specify Red as it's argb representation.